# debugging nodejs / seneca app with intellij

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea

Has anyone successfully debugged a nodejs/seneca app with intellij?

i have tried both versions 15 and 16 of the ide.

1) if i run the app everything works fine. 
2) if i debug the app without breakpoints it runs ok
3) if i place breakpoint the app just hangs until i kill the debug . the break point is never reached. in the debug window pressing the pause does nothing.

would love to know if anyone has tried this.. thanks

This a snippet of code i am trying to debug

```
var seneca = require('seneca');

var senecaConfig = {
  errhandler: senecaErrorHandler,
  timeout:99999
};

var paymentService = seneca(senecaConfig)
  .use( 'payment' )
  .use('seneca-rabbitmq-transport-v2')
  .listen( {type:'rabbitmq',url:'amqp://localhost',pin:'role:PaymentService'} )
  .client( {type:'rabbitmq',url:'amqp://localhost',pin:'role:DatabaseService,cmd:createTransaction'} )
  .client( {type:'rabbitmq',url:'amqp://localhost',pin:'role:DatabaseService,cmd:getTransactionById'} )
  .client( {type:'rabbitmq',url:'amqp://localhost',pin:'role:DatabaseService,cmd:getGatewayCfg'} )
  .client( {type:'rabbitmq',url:'amqp://localhost',pin:'role:DatabaseService,cmd:getNextSequenceNumber'} );

  var now = new Date();
  var newTransaction = {
    order_date: now.getFullYear() + '-' + now.getMonth() + '-' + now.getDay(),
    order_time: now.getHours() + ':' + now.getMinutes() + '-' + now.getSeconds(),
    ref_num: 1234567890,
    seq_num: 1234567890,
    source_id: 14,
    date_time_added: now,
  };

  paymentService.act({role:'DatabaseService',cmd:'getGatewayCfg',service:'GatewayServices',id:39},console.log);

function senecaErrorHandler( err ) {
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the [Jetbrains docs on debugging](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.1/running-and-debugging-node-js.html?origin=old_help#debugLocal)? Point 4 indicates you need to access the app via the browser to get control over debugging to return to the IDE. *Also consider using WebStorm as it's better suited to Node.js development than IntelliJ is*

Comment: webstorm is a subset of intellij. I am not sure what you mean about using the browser. this is a micro service that is a rabbitmq client. it does not have a listener that you would use a browser for. I debug nodejs apps normally just fine. it seems like it is the seneca part that messes up the debugger. I am really look for help from someone that has debugged with seneca

Comment: Strictly speaking: WebStorm is a different IDE that is *based* off IntelliJ. Otherwise, I'm not sure...It does seem to be an IDE issue that's related to how IntelliJ treats breakpoints in a Node.js app. My advice is to just read through the rest of the documentation page I linked to above and check you're doing everything right regarding Run Configurations, Debugging etc.

Comment: I agree it sounds like the ide.i guess i am wondering if anyone has successfully debugged a node app specifically using seneca and Intellij or webstorm

Comment: I've never really touched seneca. If noone responseds and you don't figure it out yourself, I suggest opening a [YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues) issue with Jetbrains regarding it.

Comment: already did, they said open with seneca. you know the drill and i am sure seneca will say it is intellij